# Pontificious - Is this a word?

Tags: single-word-requests

I recently got called incredibly pontificious - Is this a word?

I know pontificate is a word, but searching for 'pontificious' returns no actual definition of the word, not even usage in a sentence. He was adamant the reason for this is its such a rare word it won’t be used, but I’d assume someone, somewhere would have defined it or used it in a sentence if it was.

Hence why I felt it may not have been used correctly.

I have, admittedly, done a basic google search and looked a couple of online dictionaries but online results from google searches return nothing clear. Searching in the Cambridge dictionary sends me to pontificate and a search in Webster’s yields no results.

So, is it a word? If I was being pompous and dogmatic, how should he have described me?

If it is a word, why can't I find a simple definition of it?

Comment: Hello, Elliot. If you look at the Help Center, you will see that reasonable research and **evidence** of reasonable research are both required to accompany a good question here on ELU. Which dictionaries have you tried?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth To be fair to the OP a basic Google search on that word doesn't show anything concrete (as they said): no online dictionary results (other than those that say "we can't find that word"), this question and a spellchecker site that says it's spelt correctly but doesn't define it. However, the OED _does_ list it (as obsolete) with citations back to 1624.

Comment: Triple Hound has done the same as what I have. I don't have any physical dictionaries (I doubt most people do) at hand to check each one, but online results from google searches return nothing. Searching in the Cambirdge dictionary sends me to pontificate and a searching in Webster’s yields no results.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Eliott has shown enough evidence of research, if you ask me. I have flagged your comment as unfriendly because it is unwelcoming.

Comment: @Cerberus If you are referencing 'Searching in the Cambridge dictionary sends me to _pontificate_ and a search in Webster’s yields no results' , if my memory serves me right that appeared _after_ my comment. I detect a note of hostility. Have I made a comment elsewhere not to your liking?

Comment: In Edwin's defence it was added after his comment - as shown in the edit history.

Comment: Thank you, Elliot. And thanks for the addition of the research you've done, negative though the results were – it helps others to start somewhere else.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: There is no way to retract it. But feel free to flag what you consider improper. I suggest, though, that you be far less critical of new questions in the future, especially of those from new users. You're lucky that Elliot took it so well; but such comments still spoil the atmosphere for others. SE, and EL&U in particular, are trying to become friendlier places, e.g. https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/ Even when you're right and the question could be better, ask yourself: is the unwelcomingness really worth it?

Comment: @Cerberus When I joined ELU, I was gratified that there was an explanation 'ELU is not like other SE sites ...' and even more gratified when ELL was set up to answer more basic questions. I consider it an abuse of ELU when questions are presented lacking reasonable signs of research, or of a standard well below that reasonably to be expected of linguists, both obviously counter to the spirit of ELU and showing ignorance of / disregard for the recommendations in the Help Center. I feel it a _duty_ of established members to police the site, removing mediocrity and endless repetitions.

Comment: ... And if 'Hello, Sally. If you look at the Help Center, you will see that reasonable research and evidence of reasonable research are both required to accompany a good question here on ELU. Which dictionaries have you tried?' is unfriendly, it's a virtual rewrite of the standard 'Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic' minus the suggestion to switch to  ELL and with a further reasonable suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Pontificious* does indeed exist, according to the Oxford English Dictionary:

---

[image]

---

But it is obsolete. The word **pontifical**, however, is still in use:

---

[image]

---

There is also **pontificial**, which can be used in the same sense.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I guess you have to subcribe to use the OED search. My research did stumble upon a meaning of the word that was related to religion, but I guess the context he used it may not be a correct in modern day standards.

Comment: @ElliotNewton: You can also find version of the Oxford English Dictionary online, such as those which can be used in Golden Dictionary and the like.

Comment: are those screen shots from the full version? online? offline?  doesn't look like oed.com

Comment: @Toothrot: Offline. It's from Golden Dictionary.

Comment: I have never heard of the Golden Dictionary. I did try OED, but I needed a subscription to search for a term.

Comment: where did you find the oed for that?

Comment: It seems extraordinary that that marvellous bit of dialogue – "You know Mistress Shave'em?" "The pontifical punk?" – is from 1632. Can that be right?

Comment: Can I trouble you for an explanation of what the Golden Dictionary is? I searched but haven't found info on anything like this. I don't suppose you're a collector of children's books? https://www.amazon.com/Golden-Dictionary-Giant-Book/dp/B0007FWT1G

Comment: @Chappo Well, [this version from 1813](https://books.google.com/books?id=nFsrAQAAIAAJ&lpg=PA118&ots=3N_iYVjXZZ&hl=da&pg=PA74#v=onepage) certainly has it, so it seems likely enough to me. (Note that _punk_ here means ‘prostitute’, not what it currently means.)

Comment: @ElliotNewton: Golden Dictionary is a programme which can search display dictionary files. It accepts various file types.

Comment: @Toothrot: I actually don't remember, it was many years ago. But if you Google for `Oxford English Dictionary stardict` or similar, you'll probably find something. Stardict is one of the various file types which Golden Dictionary can use.

Comment: @Zebrafish, goldendict.org

Comment: This looks pretty good!  I had found another one in the dict format, but that was useless.  Thanks!

Comment: So the OED dictionary file that you used the Golden Dictionary program, can you acquire that free or do you have to pay for it?

Comment: @Zebrafish: That probably depends on your jurisdiction. If you find it for free on the Internet, I would recommend that you pay Oxford University Press, or, better, the authors of the Oxford English Dictionary—if you are rich, or once you get rich.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the [answer by Cerberus](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/501576), an internet search of "pontificious" revealed the following usages (my emphasis added):

> The Power that makes them is originally in the Emperor; but is exercised also by the Pope, although some Lawyers of the Empire that are not **Pontificious**, quarrel at him for it, and leave it doubtful also whether the Empress, the King of the Romans, other kings, or the Princes Electors, may of themselves confer this dignity.
>
> > [Source: [*Titles of Honor, Volume 2*](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=7SsoYSUy8a8C&pg=PA323&lpg=PA323&dq=pontificious&source=bl&ots=y2Xu7Voixz&sig=ACfU3U1On3YuvDKn2ilras8-ytAE853-Yg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwie0oXKweriAhVEU30KHd1gDa44FBDoATAFegQIBhAB#v=onepage&q=pontificious&f=false), by John Selden, page 323; presumably the [1631 edition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Selden#Works)]
>
> The Preface, shewing the first occasions, inducements, and maner, of the Authors conversion. The division of the Motives. 1. Into Motives out of the **Pontificious** Erroneous Doctrines. 2. Out of their dangerous and wicked Lawes.
>
> > [Source: [*The Motives of Richard Sheldon*](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=ODY3AAAAMAAJ&pg=PP38&lpg=PP38&dq=pontificious&source=bl&ots=B8_2F1OcgX&sig=ACfU3U2_nUlMk-XZcLkZFZaCvN4JY7LVaQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwie0oXKweriAhVEU30KHd1gDa44FBDoATADegQICBAB#v=onepage&q=pontificious&f=false), by Richard Sheldon, 1612]

And there's also this recent paper giving further background:

> The Oxford English dictionary is the basis of the *Historical thesaurus of the Oxford English dictionary* (2009), which is in effect a subject-ordered index to the dictionary, registering 800,000 lexical items in 235,000 entry categories. These categories ultimately fall under three highest-level headings, “the external world”, “the mind”, and “society”. A user can work down from these headings to find, for example, that “society” includes “religion”, which includes “church government”, which includes “clergyman”, which includes “clerical superior”, which includes “pope”, which includes a list of 21 adjectives with their dates of first attestation, from the fourteenth-century *papal* to the seventeenth-century *pontificious* and *papizing*, by way of the sixteenth-century *antichristian*, included on the strength of a quotation of 1585, “The head of the church Antichristian, is the Pope.”. The number of early modern forms in this list, and the absence of new forms after the seventeenth century, are both striking.
>
> [Source: John Considine, *English Dictionaries As Sources For Work In English Historical Linguistics: An Overview*, in [Studia Linguistica Universitatis Iagellonicae Cracoviensis 131 (2014): 27–41](http://www.ejournals.eu/Studia-Linguistica/Tom-131/Numer-1/art/2069/); p. 34]